# Get sum of all the row in second column in to the third column

Tags: mysql, sql

Table Scores

```
Id  Player  Score
1   John    134
2   Tom     146
3   Lucy    20
4   Tom     118
5   Tom     102
6   Lucy    90
7   Lucy    34
8   John    122
```

```
SELECT player, SUM(score) as sum_score
FROM game
GROUP BY player;
```

```
Player  Score
John    256
Tom     366
Lucy    144
```

What I am looking for is sum of all the values from second column, so that I can further find out the percentage.

> 256+366+144=766

[image]

What changes could be made to the above query to achieve the desired results, are there any windows function which can be used here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine aggregation with window functions:

```
SELECT player, SUM(score) as sum_score,
       SUM(SUM(score)) OVER () as total_score
FROM game
GROUP BY player;
```

Answer (score 1):

So generally I would recommend doing this in application code if at all possible since that will be easier to follow.  But you could use a subquery to find the total sum and include that as a column

```
SELECT 
  player, 
  SUM(score) AS player_score, 
  (SELECT SUM(score) FROM player) AS total_score
FROM
  game
GROUP BY
  player
```

I can't speak for all databases, but most databases should run the subquery only once. I can confirm that since it's an uncorrelated subquery, MySQL will only run the subquery once.  It is a bit of double work still though because we're running through the `player` table twice.

Alternatively, you could use window functions, but we'll need to make sure we select `DISTINCT` or we'll get duplicate rows in the set.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  player,
  SUM(score) OVER (PARTITION BY player) AS player_score,
  SUM(score) OVER () AS total_score
FROM
  game
;
```

Personally, I like the window functions better, but they are not always supported depending on your DBMS (or version).  Also, I've found that other people tend to get a bit more confused by window functions so depending on the expertise of the other people who may be reading the SQL, you may want to switch up which strategy you use.

Comment: The recommendation to do this in the application code is just silly.  The database is usually the best place to do processing on data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rollup`

```
select Coalesce(player,'Total') Player, Sum(score) Sum_Score
from game
group by player
with rollup
```

Comment: I don't think rollup will give you separate column.

Comment: Ah ok. I can only see the text of your question, I only have placeholders for images where I'm currently viewing.

Comment: No worries, Thanks for helping.